# Is 望む a typo for 臨む in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, words

> あのサーヴァント―アサシンには一騎打ちで望まなければ、先にマスターを叩かれてしまう……！」
>
> Against that servant, if I don't fight one on one against Assassin, my master will end up being knocked out first.

Why is で望まなければ used here?
I am pretty sure it should be 臨まなければ, but since I am still not that good with Japanese, I thought I should ask anyway.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The etymology is the same for 望む and 臨む, but you are right. When facing something (i.e. a challenge) the latter should be used.

Source: スーパー大辞林 / Super Daijirin Japanese Dictionary (2010, 2013 Sanseido Co., Ltd.)

Answer (score 1):

You are right. It’s clearly a typo or misuse of “望む” for “臨む”, though both words sound phonetically the same.

According to 広辞苑, while “臨む” means ① to face, confront. ② to go to the place, while “望む” means ① to view from a long distance. ② to desire, expect sth.

So "望まなければ” of “アサシンには一騎打ちで望まなければ - If I don't face Assassin one on one,” should be ”臨まなければ.”